# single stepping VC++ 2010 debugger from Matlab

Tags: c, matlab, visual-c++

I have a C function that I ported to Matlab

However the C version produces much better output than my Matlab version
so I want the Matlab version to produce the required data codes, load then in to a variable in C, and let C do the processing on the data points and vice versa, so that I can compare where and how the two programs work differently on the same set of data
The problem is one data set is at least 256 floats long and there are hundreds of such data sets

It would be more convenient if I could calculate the data set in Matlab, store them in a file and send an Acknowledge signal to the C debugger, so that when it gets the signal from Matlab it continues to single step through it's code, loading the data provided my matlab from the file on disk

Would it even be possible to do this? If possible I want to be able to do this in reverse as well, that is, the C program produces the data points and stores then in a file, then signals Matlab to continue to single step through it's code

EDIT:

I feel that although the VC++ 2010 debugger is very easy to use, they have made it very difficult to be used in conjunction with any other programs. So if doing this in gcc's debugger (using Codeblocks, or anything else) is possible, I would like some suggestions on how to do this (that is does not have to be VC++'s debugger)

Answer (score 0):

If you wrap up your C code as a [MEX](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/creating-c-c-and-fortran-programs-to-be-callable-from-matlab-mex-files.html) file, you can send your data directly from MATLAB into your C code. You can then attach the VS debugger to the MATLAB process, and set breakpoints as usual in your MEX file. This will allow you to single step through the MATLAB code, and then through the C code. (Note that MATLAB will be unresponsive while you're single-stepping through the C code).

Actually, one thing that I always forget about but might also be helpful here is MATLAB's [LOADLIBRARY](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/loadlibrary.html) interface. This removes the need to wrap up your C code in the MEX veneer. I've never tried, but I assume you can do the same trick here - attach the VS debugger to the running MATLAB process and set breakpoints etc.